# How to create a "function" for terminal to run

Tags: terminal, script, git

I have about 10 terminal commands that execute syncing with a Git repository and a live-server. How can I boil that down into single command? Is this a use case for scripting?

Steps include:

- Navigate to local directory.
- Add/commit/push changes to Git.
- SSH into live-server.
- Sync changes from Git.

Comment: Use a script for sure. Since you mention terminal, I'm assuming you're using a Linux system?

Comment: you should really do some googling. I'm sure you can find some good answers in no time.

Comment: Mac, Klik. Never heard of this google machine you speak of David. I came here because I wanted a trusted answer so I wouldn't just throw something together, run it, and bork my computer.

Comment: by running you X number of commands in correct sequence via one script, you are cramming them all into one command.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use either a script or a shell function. They're written pretty much the same way – start with just listing all the commands as if they were run manually, then gradually add things like checking for errors.

---

Shell functions are configured in the shell itself, in the `~/.bashrc` file for *bash* (similar for zsh, etc.), and can be only used within the interactive shell. The syntax is `name() { commands...; }`:

```
allthethings() {
    cd ~/things
    thing2 --whatever
    git thingify origin/master
}
```

Note: Whenever you edit `~/.bashrc`, it only gets re-read when opening a new terminal, or when you manually re-read it using the "dot" command: `. ~/.bashrc`.

Functions can be created directly in the interactive shell, too; they just won't be remembered.

---

Scripts are standalone files, usually in `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, starting with the `#!` interpreter line, followed by the script itself – in shell scripts it's almost exactly the same as writing a function; mainly differs in whether you use `exit` vs `return`, and whether variables & `cd` affect the interactive shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd ~/things
thing2 --whatever
git thingify origin/master
```

Note that you need to `chmod +x` the script files before they can be run directly, without having to specify 'bash' every time. (If you use `#!/usr/bin/env python`, the rest would be interpreted by Python or Ruby or whatever other language of your choice.)

Also the script directory must be listed in the `$PATH` variable. Custom locations like `~/bin` often have to be added manually, by editing `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```